# integral verification $\int_{\gamma}(y-x)dx+(z-x)dy+(x-y)dz$ where $\gamma$ is a intersection of a sphere with a plane.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

> Calculate the line integral  $$\int_{\gamma}(y-x)dx+(z-x)dy+(x-y)dz$$ where  $\gamma$ is a  circunference  obtained from the intersection of the sphere  $$S=\lbrace (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}:x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2 \rbrace$$ and the plane $S_{1}$ given by the ecuation $y=x\tan \alpha$ and
> orientation counterclockwise from positive axis $x$
> Is my approach below correct or i forget some detail, any feedback or recomendation was very helful and useful.
> Thanks so much for read me

Notice that the surface $S_{1}$ give recorres all $\mathbb{R}^3$ of form that the plane recorres all  $\alpha \in [0,\pi]$ where $\alpha \neq \pi/2$, too can assume that $a\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a\neq 0$.

the intersection of $S \cap S_{1}$ is when both equations are satisface , therefore $y=x\tan \alpha$ in $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ we get  $x^2+x^2\tan^2 \alpha+z^2=a^2$ that is equivalent to $x^2(1+\tan^2\alpha)+z^2=a^2$ Which is a circle in the plane $XZ$ Of form that we can see the surface like a
\begin{equation}
x^2\sec^2 \alpha+z^2=a^2 
\end{equation}

For  $\alpha \in [0, \pi]$ y $a\in \mathbb{R},a \neq 0$ with $\alpha \neq \pi/2$.
Dividing $(1)$ by $a^2$ we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2}{\frac{a^2}{\sec^2 \alpha}}+\frac{z^2}{a^2}=a^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2}{a^2\cos^2 \alpha}+\frac{z^2}{a^2}=a^2
\end{equation}
Notice $(3)$ is a easy equation of parametrize.

Let $t\in [0,\pi/2]$ y $\alpha \in [0, \pi]$ with $\alpha \neq \pi/2,a \neq 0$ then
\begin{equation}
x=a\cos \alpha \sin t
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
z=a\cos t
\end{equation}
Is one parametrization of the intersection $S \cap S_{1}$ of form that found
$\frac{dx}{dt}=a\cos \alpha \cos t$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$, $\frac{dz}{dt}=-a\sin t$ and remplazion in the integral

$$\int_{\gamma}(y-x)dx+(z-x)dy+(x-y)dz=4 \int_{0}^{\pi/2}{(-a^2\cos^2 \alpha  \sin t \cos t-a^2\cos \alpha \sin^2 t)dt}$$
since
$$4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{(-a^2\cos^2 \alpha  \sin t \cos t-a^2\cos \alpha \sin^2 t)dt}=-a^2\cos \alpha(2\cos \alpha+ \pi)$$ then
$$\int_{\gamma}(y-x)dx+(z-x)dy+(x-y)dz=-a^2\cos \alpha(2\cos \alpha+ \pi)$$

Comment: "the surface $S_1$ give recorres all $\Bbb R^3$ of form that the plane recorres all $\alpha \in [0,\pi]$" - Even after looking up the translation for "recorres", I cannot figure out what you mean by this.

Comment: $S\cap S_1$ is *not* a circle (or an ellipse) in the $XZ$ plane. $y = x \tan\alpha$, not $0$. The ellipse $x^2\sec^2 \alpha + z^2 = a^2$ is the *projection* of $S\cap S_1$ into the $XZ$ plane, not the intersection itself. Also when you divide by $a^2$, you need to divide *both sides* of the equation by $a^2$ - but you recovered from that mistake by getting the $x$ and $z$ parametrizations correct anyway.